# How to add multiple types of objects to json array?

Tags: c#, json

I need to parse data to JSON in a particular format, which should look like this (notice that there are multiple types of objects in an array).

```json
{
    "member details":
        [
            {
                "name": "John Doe",
                "type": "faculty",
                "teaching years": "5",
                "faculty code": "f154"
            },
            {
                "name": "Mary Storm",
                "type": "student",
                "studying years": "3",
                "student code": "s19"
            }
        ]
}
```

How can I add multiple objects to a JSON array?

I was thinking of interfaces. But what if none of the properties are common?

Comment: Can you  explain what your are trying to reach pls?  Use just Jobject.parse and you can parse any kind of json, as far as  the json is valid. Can you show the code you used to create this json pls?

Comment: If you're c# code are objects contained in a `List<T>` where `T` is of a base type of the objects you contain, then JsonSerializer.Serialize(yourListName) should write the json in the above format automatically.  But adding your code would be best for others to comment on.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. I've edited it to make it clearer. This JSON is the output that I desire (I haven't generated it yet). So, there is no code, until I find a solution to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is a shared base type (could be `object`, for example):

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var values = new object[]
        {
            new A { PropertyA = "A value" },
            new B { PropertyB = "B value" },
        };
        
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(values));
    }
    
    public class A
    {
        public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class B
    {
        public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/R2zUi2

Answer (score 0):

#### A. No common properties

> But what if none of the properties are common?

In such case the objects should not be in the same collection.

#### B. Some common properties

##### B1. Separate collections

Separate the different types of objects into separate collections. It really makes the serialisation and deserialisation easy.

```
public class Org 
{
    List<Students> Students {get; set;}
    List<Teacher> Teachers {get; set;}
}

var teachers = new Teacher[] {
    new Teacher { FirstName = "Lucy", FacultyYears = 3},
};

var students = new Teacher[] {
    new Student { FirstName = "Luca", StudyingYears = 3}
};

var org = new Org
{
    Teachers = teachers,
    Students = students
}
```

##### B2. Use a base type

Rather than using `object[]` as Moho suggest I think using a base class `Person` would be more correct:

```
var members = new Person[] {
    new Teacher { FirstName = "Lucy", FacultyYears = 3},
    new Student { FirstName = "Luca", StudyingYears = 3}
};


class Person {
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
}

class Teacher : Person {
    public int FacultyYears { get; set;}
}

class Student : Person {
    public int StudyingYears { get; set;}
}
```

###### Note on Polymorphic collections and json

Please note that if you use polymorphic collections deserialisation (json -> objects) is not that obvious.

##### B3. Single shared model

It **may** be easier (it **really** depends on the scenario) to have a single type. For the collection shown it could be:

```
class Member {
    public string FirstName {get; set;} 
    
    public Role Role {get;set;}

    public int Years {get; set;} // If student this meas student years, if teacher it means faculty years 

    public string Code {get; set;} // If student this means student code, if teacher this means faculty years
}
```

Comment: This is a model that I've made for this question for simplicity. However, the project I'm working on requires objects that have no properties in common, so what @moho said works for me.